# On save, Vue generates false errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have started a pretty empty Vue projet, then when I do the following it works...

```
npm run serve
```

Then I change a minor thing in my project and hit CTRL+S. The Vue instance is rebuilt and then I have some weird errors such as:

```
error: Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved at src/main.js:1:1:
> 1 | import Vue from 'vue'
```

So if I quit and rerun `npm run serve` it works again.

What's wrong?

Comment: can you show what you changed?

Comment: I changed absolutely nothing relevant  (added a space in the file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be the eslint configuration problem, try to add this to your .eslintrc.js file to enable es6 modules

```
parserOptions: {
 sourceType: 'module'
},
```